# Create App Catalog using SharePoint Online Management Shell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site-template

How can I create an app catalog site for a SharePoint tenant using the SharePoint Online PowerShell?
When calling the `Get-SPOWebTemplate` command, there is no `APPCATALOG#0` template which may be SharePoint-2013-only. I can however create a Team Site (`STS#0`) so is it possible to create one and then set this as the app catalog site using SharePoint Online PowerShell?
From my research so far it seems that this may not be possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think you can not create a App Catalog using powershell In Office 365.

The only way is you have to login on with admin account and go to  SharePoint admin center. and create App catlog here.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-App-Catalog-to-make-custom-business-apps-available-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-0b6ab336-8b83-423f-a06b-bcc52861cba0?CorrelationId=1296e0be-43bc-4561-b67c-5ad1a81f7b69&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/191596.aspx

Comment: Can we update any of the properties of App catalog site collection using SPOL Powershell like title, storage quota etc?

Comment: Am I right that we cannot create SP Online App Catalog having SP Online plans as we need Admin Center which is only available in Office 365 Subscriptions?

Comment: I wonder if this is still the case 3 years later. I regularly have to create new Office 365 tenants and I would love to automate App catalog creation step.